# Method::Signatures, order of function output in module

Tags: perl, sequence, func

I am writing my own module, in which I have defined three functions:

```
package YUCO::Test;

use 5.008008;
use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;
use AutoLoader qw(AUTOLOAD);
use Method::Signatures;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ qw() ] );
our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );
our @EXPORT = qw( Test1 Test2 Test3 );
our $VERSION = '0.01';

#-----------------------------------------------------
func Test1( Str $a='' )
{
        print ' ok from Test1, and a is : '.$a."\n";
}

#-----------------------------------------------------
func Test2( Str $a='' )
{
        print ' ok from Test2, and a is : '.$a."\n";
}

#-----------------------------------------------------
func Test3( Str $a='' )
{
        print ' ok from Test3, and a is : '.$a."\n";
}

#-----------------------------------------------------

1;
__END__
```

and then when i do a test program with these lines :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use YUCO::Test qw( Test1 Test2 Test3 );

Test1( 'a ar' );
Test2( 'b lo' );
Test3( '..c..' );

Test1();
Test2();
Test3();
```

it has output like these, which has some strange/random output sequence :

> ```
> ok from Test2, and a is : b lo
> ok from Test3, and a is : ..c..
> ok from Test2, and a is :
> ok from Test3, and a is :
> ok from Test1, and a is : a ar
> ok from Test1, and a is :
> ```

but they are not exact random in the sense that every time i run the script it would have the exact sequence like this.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check how the code mangler is mangling your darlings by doing the following:

```
use Data::Dumper qw<Dumper>;

$Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;

say Dumper( \&YUCO::Test::Test1 );
```

Perhaps that might give you a clue.